# How to use a CSS for only one div and not the rest of the code?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I imported this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

And it started to affect other things in my page, such as buttons.

How can I tell my html to **only use that stylesheet for this code**?

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can download `bootstrap.css`, remove the unnecessary things from it and make a `link` reference to a `bootstrap-mysite.css`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add following css to your own css file, and dont add bootstrap.css if you need one single class, it makes site lot heavy.
(Extracted from bootstrap itself)

```
.progress {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
.progress-bar {
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
          box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -webkit-transition: width .6s ease;
       -o-transition: width .6s ease;
          transition: width .6s ease;
}
.progress-striped .progress-bar,
.progress-bar-striped {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  -webkit-background-size: 40px 40px;
          background-size: 40px 40px;
}
.progress.active .progress-bar,
.progress-bar.active {
  -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
          animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}
.progress-bar-success {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}
.progress-striped .progress-bar-success {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-bar-info {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}
.progress-striped .progress-bar-info {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-bar-warning {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.progress-striped .progress-bar-warning {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-bar-danger {
  background-color: #d9534f;
}
.progress-striped .progress-bar-danger {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Bootstrap Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) page. Select only the Progress bar option and download the files. You are ready to go!